# Etiquette to recontact the editor when he says the he will give the news as soon as he has some

Tags: peer-review, etiquette, editors

Assume that the last time that one has contacted the editor of a journal (about 10 months ago) to obtain the progress of submitted manuscript, the editor has said that he will give news as soon as he has some news.

In this circumstance isn't it rude to recontact him again to obtain news from the progress of the manuscript?

Other relevant informations: (1) The editor is very responsive and the journal is reputated.

(2) I have submitted my paper 26 months ago to this journal.

Edit: The question [How long after first contact, where editor says "manuscript is still under review", is it okay to enquire again about status of manuscript?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/84964/how-long-after-first-contact-where-editor-says-manuscript-is-still-under-revie) is relevant but the difference between my question and that one is that since my last inquiry 10 months has passed but in that question 2 months has passed.

Answer (score 2):

Although it's arguably dependent on field, 10 months is well past the time it should take to be able to provide a status update.

I remember reading this story about a woman who was bedridden for years. A doctor eventually examined her and found nothing wrong at all. Asked what the problem was, the woman said a previous doctor had left instructions for her to stay in bed "until he returned". The previous doctor evidently forgot about it, and the woman just followed instructions. This situation is similar.